# Handling Timestamp Excel columns in Apache POI - Java

Tags: java, oracle, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read the excel data and I am processing them in Java.
The data to be processed is in an Excel sheet and this is populated from Toad. The backend is Oracle, so the datatypes also include Date and Timestamp columns which is populated in the Excel in this format
For Date : 07/01/2012 00:00:00
For Timestamp : 01/07/2012 00:00:00.000.

The excel file name is static but the data that it contains would differ as it is populated with data from different tables/views at different intervals.

I am able to handle DATE columns using

```
//Set the date format for the data fields
HSSFCellStyle dateStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
short dateFormat = workBook.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateStyle.setDataFormat(dateFormat);
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();

if (hssfCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    //Check if data in the cell is a date
    if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(hssfCell))
        hssfCell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
```

**Problem**:
But when it comes to TIMESTAMP columns, HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC doesn't hold true for those cells and thus HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted doesn't work with them. So I am not able to specify a format for the TIMESTAMP columns. 
I compare the data in the excel with the actual data in Oracle tables by querying them (using Java), due to this formatting issue, they don't match.

I am new to Java and POI, so probably would have missed something silly here.
Any inputs on how I can solve this issue?

**Update**

After browsing the web for an alternative solution, for the time being I have taken a static approach where I expect the Timestamp data to be of specific format

```
String timestampIn = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
String timestampOut = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
try
{
    Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat(timestampIn)).parse(fmt.formatCellValue(hssfCell).toString().trim());
    //Add data in the cell to the ArrayList
    cellTempList.add((new SimpleDateFormat(timestampOut)).format(date));
}
catch (ParseException pe) {
    //Add data in the cell to the ArrayList
    cellTempList.add(fmt.formatCellValue(hssfCell));
}
```

This only works if the timestamp format in the Excel is of this format - dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS.

Any effective solution for addressing timestamp values in different format will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, There is an easy way to do it.

Take the Column Name which is has TIMESTAMP datatype from DB and compare with your Excel Sheet's Header.

If the Excel Header matches with the Column Name of DB, then have a seperate SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'") and perform your activities.

Is it fine to you?

Comment: I am not familiar with this approach - Class _class = Class.forName(columnNo); Can you provide some details on how can I extract the class details of the excel column using this?

Comment: I already thought about this approach but this would introduce complexity as the current implementation extracts the excel data first, populates them into arraylist and then runs the actual query to compare against the excel data. The actual query can be a simple query, function, procedure or even anyonymous block. So I was looking for a simple solution like the one you suggested earlier where I would be able to check the excel column to see if it is a timestamp without introducing any dependency with the database. Is your first suggestion feasible and easy to implement?